# JQuery draggable and droppable append issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I want to drag a div to a droppable div and have the droppable div 'contain it' while the initial draggable div is still draggable within the droppable.

However,

When I drag the draggable div to the droppable div the draggable div is appended in a manner that is visually offset.

To cut through the above nursery rhyme and see what I actually mean see the fiddle below and drag **thing1** or **thing2** to the gray palette.

*It offsets to the right.*

http://jsfiddle.net/mnmyS/

I want to know how to fix that.

```
$(".card").draggable();

$('.box').draggable().resizable();



$(".pallette").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        $(".card").draggable({containment: $(this)});
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC2q/

Comment: Close but no,  I want to be able to drag the inner div anywhere inside the host droppable div. Your version kind of "floats" it to the left and restrains movement vertically

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue before some day. After a lot of effort I found a solution for me. I simply removed the draggable element when it dropped and again created a same element inside the droppable element. I know its not your solution. But may be this can help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/D3cxz/

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "30%";
div.style.height = "10%";
div.className = "card";
div.id = "draggable";
div.innerHTML = "thing1";
div.style.fontSize="small";

    document.body.appendChild(div);
    $('.card').draggable();

    var box = document.createElement("div");
    box.className = "box";

    document.body.appendChild(box); 
    $('.box').draggable();

    var pallette = document.createElement("div");
    pallette.className = "pallette";

    box.appendChild(pallette);


    $('.pallette').droppable({
         drop: function (event, ui) {
        div.parentElement.removeChild(div);

           var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div1.style.width = "30%";
        div1.style.height = "10%";
        div1.className = "card";
        div1.id = "draggable";
        div1.innerHTML = "thing1";
        div1.style.fontSize="small";
              pallette.appendChild(div1);

             $('.card').draggable(
                 {
                     containment: '.pallette'
                 });
         }});
```